# How do I position UITableView programmatically while using iOS7's UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios7

I have a quite regular `UIViewController` that is a part of a `UINavigationController`-hierarchy, which naturally makes the view have a `UINavigationBar` at the top. As we all know, iOS7's navigation bars are very different from previous versions.

If I drag a `UITableView` into my view in Storyboard, then the 'frame' for the table view is covering the entire view (I.E `[tableView setFrame:self.view.frame];`). Even behind the `NavigationBar`. 
This makes so that if I scroll, the content will be faintly visible through the bar.
Contrary to most people, I actually like this.

In my current view controller, I would like to create the `UITableView` programmatically and place it as a subview here. However, I am unable to achieve the same effect this way.

I have tried

```
UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview: table];
```

This makes the 'top scrolling point' stay behind the navigation bar. Imagine a single cell in a tableView, and it's faintly visible through the top bar. If I scroll down, it pops right up behind it. That's the default 'top position'.

I have also tried

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 'nav.y+nav.height', self...width, self...height-y);    
UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.view addSubview: table];
```

to simply place the table view in the rect below the `UINavigationBar`, but then I won't get the scrolling transparency effect behind the bar.

I also tried the first example along with this:

```
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 'below navbar')];
```

which makes it stay exactly where I want it to stay, but as soon as I touch it (scroll and release), it scrolls back up behind the navigation bar, and stays there.

What's the programmatic solution to achieve this effect? Do I have to set the offset every time I scroll too far up, or is there a simpler solution? Along with this iOS7-style, I'd imagine they would add something like `[tableView setVisibleFrame:]` or something..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the table in storyboard like normal but make sure you have it connected to an outlet (we will call it `_tableView` for now).

Then in your view controller's `-viewDidLoad` set the top inset to be the status bar plus the navigation bar:

`self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake( (self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height), 0, 0, 0);'

This will make sure that all of the cells will be visible but will also fill the area behind the navigation bar with white so the bar doesn't end up gray.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I've never even heard the word `inset` before, but this was exactly what I was looking for. For the record, the question was directly targeted at programmatically creating a tableView, and not adding through Storyboard and using Outlets. Anyway, your line of code  directly after my first 'example' did the trick, thank you.